# Best way to add items to the front of a RecycleAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to add items to the front of recyclerview, but I need to keep the scroll focused at the previous viewed item.

So I'm scrolling recyclerview to previous top item:

```
for (Item item : items)
     mItems.add(0, item);
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, items.size());
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(items.size() - 1);
```

Is there a better solution? This is very jittery.

Comment: what adapter are you using? there is no such thing as pushFront

Comment: I updated with better code. I was using a custom defined adapter.

Comment: if you want to scroll to the top of the list when things get inserted then what you are doing is correct

Comment: I don't really want to do that, though. I want to keep the scroll focussed on whatever the user was previously viewing. When you scroll to the top of a messaging client, they load more messages at the top without shifting your current scroll. Is there a way to do this in RecycleAdapter?

Comment: ah I see what you are saying now, no there is no way to do that besides what you are doing. see this issue for a comment from one of the developers https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=174227 in short `RecyclerView tries to keep its view port visible not the positions`. The hangouts app has this "jitter" too

Comment: Ah ok, much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what @tyczj said, there is no solution to this.